# Google places API - V2- Autocomplete does not show all the place results

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to follow the android documentation, but its does not show me all the suggestions for the places. Like for example if I write cluster Z. This will not show me any suggestions. Exactly what i want is If I type location X2, it should return me X1,X2 itself,X3,X4,X5, because i am surrounded by these locations. What am i missing ?

```
private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
ArrayList<String> resultList = null;
//API KEY = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; // Enter Your Key

private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + "Enter Your Key");
        sb.append("&components=country:myCountry");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        // Load the results into a StringBuilder
        int read;
        char[] buff = new char[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
            jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        return resultList;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        return resultList;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    try {
        // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
        JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

        // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
        resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
            resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
    }

    Log.v("returnResult",""+resultList.toString());
    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: can you give me place key or check url with key in your browser..is it right url & key  or not

Comment: i have recently integrated it , it works fine, u need to pass location as well to get accurate results.

Comment: follow this tutorail might help you. http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/

Comment: I want perfect result, i added locations, radius to get more precise, but no help.

Comment: @droid: have followed that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Google Search Box instead of Autocomplete if you want to show all result showed in Google map searchbox

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to replace all of that code with a single library method call, you could check out [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) (disclosure: I'm the developer).  The equivalent would be something like:

```
Places.autocomplete(Params.create().query(input)).getResult()
```

[Places Javadoc](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/google/Places.html)

You could also take a look at the [GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html) widget, which does everything for you and provides the [Place](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/google/Place.html) that the user selects.

```
<net.sf.sprockets.widget.GooglePlaceAutoComplete
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[GooglePlaceAutoComplete Javadoc](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html)